# Gitlab-Runner: Permission denied on cloning from master

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, docker-in-docker

I was looking for a method to implement a CI/CD pipeline within my projects. I decided to use Gitlab with its gitlab-runner technology. I tried to use it through docker containers but, after more than 100 attempts, I decided to install it on the machine.

I followed the official [Gitlab guide](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/) step by step. Everything is working perfectly; I run the register, fill all the fields correctly and I go on to write the .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: docker:latest

services:
- docker:18.09.9-dind

stages:
  - deploy

step-deploy-prod:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - docker-compose up -d --build
  when: always
  environment: master
```

As you can imagine when looking at the yml file, when some operation is performed on the master, the pipeline starts and executes a docker-compose up --build -d (the project in question is a PHP application with a SQL database deployed through a compose).

**First run:**
Absolutely perfect; the pipeline starts, the build is executed correctly and is correctly put in online

**Second and following 140 runs:**
That's the nightmare. Over 140 builds failed for the same reason; when cloning the repository, the runner doesn't seem to have write permissions on his home directory (/home/gitlab-runner/builds/...).

[image]

**If I manually delete the nested folder inside builds/ the runner works, but only for one run, then same situation.**

I tried to:

- run chown gitlab-runner:gitlab-runner on its home directory (also as
  pre_clone_script in the TOML file);
- add gitlab-runner to the sudoers group;
- I added gitlab-runner to the docker group;
- a series of file permissions operations, then chmod 777, chgrp with
  the runner group and more.

Comment: 1. How did you install the gitlab runner? paste the command please
2. Paste the permissions of the path before the first job

I think you need to reinstall the runner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You always should not  forget to stop your containers with `after_script` section.

But in your case, you can use [GIT_STRATEGY](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/README.html#git-strategy)  to clear repository before your job.

```
  variables: 
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
```

Your yml file with this fix

```
image: docker:latest

services:
- docker:18.09.9-dind

stages:
  - deploy

step-deploy-prod:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - docker-compose up -d --build
  when: always
  environment: master
  variables: 
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
```